# Change default page in yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm fairly new to yii, would like to know how to change the default page pra that instead of going to the index is directed to a page comingsoon I have.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1: Change view page rendered in SiteController.php's index action:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $this->render('index'); // change to "comingsoon"
}
```

Method 2: Let 404 error page display a coming soon message.

Method 3: Redirect to error page using URL manager rules in main.php:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'rules' => array(
        'index'=>'site/index', // change "site/index" to "site/comingsoon"
        ...
```

Method 4: `.htaccess` rewrite.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new controller with it's own view: comingsoon (see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii).

Add this in:
**protected\config\main.php**

```
'defaultController' => 'comingsoon',
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify which controller and action to be default.
Add this to main.php

```
'defaultController'=>'site/index', // controller/action
```

There no need to edit anything on controller :)

If there is any problem I think you need to edit also the **.htaccess** (For Friendly Url)
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, just change the view to the location of the comingsoon view.

Comment: Yes, but there is a way to change the controller, because when you want to access the index while developing'll have to do another controller?

Comment: Im a little confused. Do you just want to change the view that is displayed or redirect them from www.yoursite.com/index.php to www.yoursite.com/comingsoon.php ? If its a redirect your doing, you have 2 options: either use a header('location:') command or change your sites Routes.php config

Comment: yep, just change your main.php. (Sorry for earlier, routes.php is Codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to specify [defaultIndex](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#defaultAction-detail) as a class variable in your controller:

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    public $defaultIndex = 'comingSoon';

    public function actionComingSoon() {

        $this->renderPartial( ... etc .... );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is you can change urlmanager options like this by denoting the default page as empty charachter

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'admin' => 'admin/index',
        ''=>'admin/index'
```